# Powershell Script : What is the best method to quickest delete a lot of lines in big file?

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm blocked with my PowerShell script... it makes too long time to do the job. Please, I need your help to use a better method for delete a lot of lines in a file.

I explain the context :

I've two files in entered.
File1 : A List of client number and activities, who look like that :

1. 730;12345678
2. 710;11223344
3. 732;89898989
4. (etc.)

This file is filled by user, so it may contain 10 lines or 1000 lines

I added this file in array list :

```
$MyArrayList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
$File1 = get-content "file1.txt"
foreach($Client in $File1)
{
         $DetailClient = $Client.split(";")
         $NumAct = $DetailClient[0]
         $NumClient = $DetailClient[1]
         $MyArrayList.Add($NumAct)
         $MyArrayList.Add($NumClient)
}
```

File2 : It's a flow file, with 100 000 lines (in average), look like that

**LP** RC05808          094100008832970954001000088329        **12345678**                ***000006***
UO RC05808          094107               13596710435866   CAR              000001001000001
UO RC05808          094109                                COP              000013001000013
UO RC05808          094110                                PAL              000013011000143
**LT** RC05808          09410000000207700000003190PE0109202015092020R**730**
**LT** RC05808          09410000000207700000003190PE0109202015092020R**720**
**LR** RC05808          094124082020150920202 002              000000170000V  N                 **720**                                                  2133            01CAR
**UL** RC05808          09412 002              CAR              07               102         V
LR RC05808          094124082020150920202 003              000000060000V  N                 720                                                  2133            01CAR
UL RC05808          09412 003              CAR              07               36          V
LR RC05808          094124082020150920202 ***004***              000000050000V  N                 730                                                  2133            01CAR
UL RC05808          09412 ***004***              CAR              07               ***30***          V
LR RC05808          094124082020150920202 ***005***              000000100000V  N                 730                                                  2133            01CAR
UL RC05808          09412 ***005***              CAR              07               ***60***          V

In this file, i need to do for each client matched, save it for build a other file and delete it in this file, like that :
For each LP line, check if number client is present in file1
if yes, look at on LT line if activites of this client is present in file and if yes delete it
then if yes, delete every LR lines with activite number and each UL line following

For every lines deleted, i need save somes informations (in this example save 000006, 004, 005, 30, 60 for LP, UL and LR lines) to build csv file.

I hope is clear :S

I tried to read file2 fully and save all informations, and then read a second time file2 to delete lines :

```
$File2 = get-content "file2.txt"
$SaveOPC = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.ArrayList"
foreach($Fope in $File2)
{
      $Typeline = $Fope.substring(0,2)
      IF($Typeline -eq "LP")
      {
            $ClientLP = $Fope.substring(58,8)
            IF($MyArrayList.Contains($ClientLP))
            {
                 $empAct = (($MyArrayList.IndexOf($ClientLP)) -1)
                 $arrayAct = $MyArrayList.Item($emplacementAct)
                 $Keyline = $Fope.substring(3,21)
                 $SaveOPC.Add($Keyline)
                 $SaveOPC.Add($arrayAct)
            }
      }
      #[...] i do other task for every case but not useful for here
}

#delete line, it's here my problem, it's very long...
for($i=0; $i -lt $SaveOPC.count;$i=$i+2)
{
        $key = $SaveOPC.Item($i)
        $act = $SaveOPC.Item($i+1)
        $regexlrlt = '^(LR|LT) ('+$key+').*'+$act+'.*\n(UL) ('+$key+').*'
        (Get-Content "file2.txt" -Raw) -replace $regexlrlt, '' | Set-Content 'file2.txt'
}
# next i delete emply line
(Get-Content "file2.txt") | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | Set-Content "file2.txt"

#[...] then i build csv file
```

in this example, client number 12345678 matched with file1 so i must to delete Line LT with 730, LR line with 730 and the next UL line

So, my problem is how quickest to delete all matched lines... i tried line by line, by regex, by line number, etc
thanks in advance